# How to prove a number is odd using propositional logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

> How would I got about proving a number is odd using propositional logic?

An odd number is $2k+1$ essentially the result of an even number +1 which gives you an odd number. For example $5$ is the result of $4+1$, $4$ being the odd number this is how I went about showing how a number is odd, but how would I do this using propositional logic? Would the way I used above to show that a number is odd be an informal or formal proof?

Comment: Not *propositional* logic but *predicate* logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the realm of integers, one may define "$n$ is odd" as
$$ \neg\exists k\colon n=2\cdot k$$
or as 
$$ \neg\exists k\colon n=k+ k$$
while some authors may indeed define it as
$$ \exists k\colon n=2\cdot k+1.$$
Which *definition* an author uses is perhaps somewhat up to taste. Of course, it should be noted that all three definitions are (provably) equivalent (in the realm of $\Bbb Z$ as well as $\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$, but not in $\Bbb Z_{>0}$). Of course, the last variant is easier to use in a *constructive* proof that some specific $n$ is odd (namely, by exhibiting some  $k$ with $n=2k+1$).